# Algorithm for filtering table

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, pandas

1. The following is the raw dataset for *one candidate* (df_wrong).
2. It has some rows which are correct and some which are not. A row is considered incorrect if the timestamp for a stage does not follow the corresponding order logic for stage_names. For ex: Stage names must occur in the order of [Applied, Screen call, Hometask, Hometask review, 1st interview, 2nd interview, etc.]. Each stage can only occur once and must occur consecutively in the order shown above

So this is df_wrong:

```
df_wrong = pd.DataFrame({'stage_name':['Applied', 'Screen call', 'Hometask', '2nd interview',
                                            'Hometask review','Screen call', '2nd interview' ],
                       'stage_num': [1,2,3,6,4,2,6], 
                       'stage_time_mooving_in': ['2018-08-10 12:00:00', '2018-08-10 13:00:00', '2018-08-10 14:00:00',
                                               '2018-08-10 15:00:00', '2018-08-10 16:00:00', '2018-08-10 17:00:00',
                                                 '2018-08-10 19:00:00']})
```

And I want to create an algorithm, that will convert wrong table in right one:

```
df_right = pd.DataFrame({'stage_name':['Applied', 'Screen call', 'Hometask', 'Hometask review',
                                        '2nd interview' ],
                   'stage_num': [1,2,3,4,6], 
                   'stage_time_mooving_in': ['2018-08-10 12:00:00', '2018-08-10 13:00:00', 
                                           '2018-08-10 14:00:00', '2018-08-10 16:00:00',
                                            '2018-08-10 19:00:00']})
```

My question is how to create such algorithm. I try to sort df and remove duplicates, but I don't know how make it works for all cases.

All stages, that can be in my pipeline listed in this table:

```
full_pipeline =  pd.DataFrame({'stage_name':['Applied', 'Screen call', 
                                       'Hometask',  'Hometask review',
                                     '1st interview', '2nd interview', 
                                           'Final interview','Offer'],
                   'stage_num': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7 ,8]})
```

NOTE: There is some suggestion, that can help in creating algorithm:

1. First and last rows are always correct due to way of filling in.
2. Note all stages can be in this table.

Answer (score 0):

After conversation with colleagues was suggested this answer:

```
def lis(a):
    L = []
    for (k,v) in enumerate(a):
        L.append(max([L[i] for (i,n) in enumerate(a[:k]) if n<v] or [[]], key=len) + [k])
    return max(L, key=len)


right_index = lis(list(df_wrong.loc[:,'stage_num']))
df_wrong[df_wrong.index.isin(right_index)]
```

Feel free to suggest your own solutions